# clear cache automatically in pentaho community bi server

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I want to automatically clear out the CDA-catch, instead of doing manually every time.
I changed the **diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds** property in **ecatch.xml** file but no luck.

Any other way i can achieve this same.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make a HTTP request to `http://localhost:8080/pentaho/content/cda/clearCache`

See [Thread: Refresh CDA cache from a URL](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?82885-Refresh-CDA-cache-from-a-URL) Pentaho forum.

Comment: not working ..
i guess along with this i have to specify specific CDA file name.. how can i do that?

Comment: i found scheduling option for caching through user consol..
but that will only work in static query.

Comment: https://shahumang.wordpress.com/2016/04/01/create-real-time-dashboard-in-pentaho-bi-server-community-edition/